# Routing in angular2 from database

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

In my application I have URLs:

- exampledomain.com/category/1
- exampledomain.com/category/2
- exampledomain.com/page/23
- exampledomain.com/item/322

And it works, but I want the url like this:

- exampledomain.com/categoryName1
- exampledomain.com/nameCategory2
- exampledomain.com/pageContact
- exampledomain.com/about
- exampledomain.com/itemIphone
- exampledomain.com/phoneTwo

All urls are stored in the database (there are a lot of them) how to make routing based on these urls?

It stores them in the database, because it is to be edited by client

Comment: So you're asking about how to assign routes dynamically ?

Comment: Yes, i want: routes dynamically and possibility use url like from apache module mod_rewrite. It is possible?